# Updating model after unchecking all checkboxes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox

I have a form to create a device that selects which users will have a device. So one of the fields are with checkboxes selecting the users:

```
<% User.all.each do |user| %>
  <label class="checkbox-inline">
    <%= f.check_box :user_ids, {:multiple => true}, user.id, nil  %> <%= user.name %>
  </label>
<% end >
```

It generates:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="1" name="device[user_ids][]" id="device_user_ids_1">
<input type="checkbox" value="2" name="device[user_ids][]" id="device_user_ids_2">
<input type="checkbox" value="3" name="device[user_ids][]" id="device_user_ids_3">
<input type="checkbox" value="4" name="device[user_ids][]" id="device_user_ids_4">
```

When editing an object, if I check anyone of the boxes, the param `:user_ids` is passed to the controller with the other parameters. But if I do not check any box, in case I do not want any user to be linked to a device at the moment, the param `:user_ids` does not exist when the parameters are passed to the controller.

What do I do to make `"user_ids"=>[]` as a parameter when none checkbox is checked?

Comment: What code does `f.check_box` generate? Add it to your post. I _thought_ that Rails `check_box` generators added a `<input type="hidden" name="user_ids">`, before the checkbox, to fix your exact situation, the disappearing parameter bug.

Comment: I updated the question. It generates what I was expecting...

Comment: You have to check in your controller if none of the checkboxes are chekcked and remove all the `user_ids` from the device object

Comment: @Subash but How can I check it in the controller if the parameter is not being passed?

Comment: @LuizHenrique you can do `params[:device][:user_ids].length` to see if there are any ids selected

Answer (score 1):

You can declare a hidden field for checkboxes inside form it will be sent empty when checkbox is not checked

```
<%= f.hidden_field "device[user_ids][]", nil %>
```

Then

```
<% User.all.each do |user| %>
    <label class="checkbox-inline">
        <%= f.check_box :user_ids, {:multiple => true}, user.id, name:  'device[user_ids][]' %> <%= user.name %>
    </label>
<% end >
```

Hope to help